a Sum Involving Elementary Symmetric Polynomials and Quadratic Exponents
I'm trying to compute the sum
$
S(y)= \sum_{s=0}^n e_s(x_1,…,x_n) y^{s^2}
$
where $e_s$ is the elementary symmetric polynomial of order $s$, and $x_1, ..., x_n, y$ are all positive real numbers. One way to do this is by computing all elementary symmetric polynomials in $O(n^2)$ and then computing the sum. But I was wondering if this can be done more efficiently, by using the generating function of the elementary symmetric functions. That is, $E(y) = \sum_{s=0}^n e_s(x_1,…,x_n) y^s = \prod_{s=1}^n(1+x_sy)$. I'm hoping to find something $O(n)$ or $O(n\log(n))$.
I tried two ways that I'll briefly discuss below, and am wondering if there is a better way that I'm missing.

Let $\sigma = \log(y)$ and consider the integral $\exp(\sigma s^2) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_\mathbb{R} \exp(2\sqrt{\sigma}s\eta -\eta^2)\mathrm{d}\eta$. Then we obtain $$\begin{align}S(y)&= \int_\mathbb{R}\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}} \exp(-\eta^2) \sum_{s=0}^n e_s(x_1,…,x_n) \exp(2\sqrt{\sigma}s\eta) \mathrm{d}\eta\\&= \int_\mathbb{R}\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}} \exp(-\eta^2) \prod_{s=1}^n(1+x_s\exp(2\sqrt{\sigma}\eta))\mathrm{d}\eta.\end{align}$$ I used Gauss-Hermite quadrature to compute the integral numerically, but the result was inaccurate for large $y$ and thus large $\sigma$.

Let $\mathbf{z}$ be a vector such that $z_s = y^{s^2}$, $\mathbf{B}$ a diagonal matrix with $B_{ss} = e_s(x_1,…,x_n)$, $b_{s}$ is a vector with elements $e_s(x_1,…,x_n)$ , and $\mathbf{V}$ a (transposed) Vandermonde matrix where $\mathbf{V}_{ij} = \{t^2,-t^2,t^4,-t^4, ...\}_{j}^{i-1}$. Note that each column of $\mathbf{V}$ is a polynomial with linearly increasing powers, so $\mathbf{b}^T\mathbf{V1} = E(t^2) + E(-t^2) + E(t^4) + ...$, a linear combination of the generating functions. We can restate the problem as solving $\mathbf{BVa} = \mathbf{Bz}$ for $\mathbf{a}$. Then, $S(y) = \mathbf{b}^T\mathbf{z} = \mathbf{b}^T\mathbf{Va}$. This simplifies to $\mathbf{Va} = \mathbf{z}$ and the problem becomes independent of $x_1, ..., x_n$. Essentially the problem is now to (efficiently) express the vector $\mathbf{z} = [1, t, t^4, t^9,...]$ as a linear combination of polynomials with a linear progression in their powers. Some experiments with Mathematica showed me that the solutions $a$ are rational functions of $t$ that explode as $n$ increases.


Any thoughts or ideas on how to approach this efficiently?

For 1., have you tried the trapezoidal rule? The integrand (wrt the weight $e^{-\eta^2}$) you consider is not a polynomial so Gauss-Hermite quadrature won't be accurate. The trapezoidal rule is an easy and accurate method. Perhaps also consider sinh-sinh quadrature  https://docs.juliahub.com/DoubleExponentialFormulas/nxC0M/0.1.0/
